# calling alloca() multiple times results in a contiguous part of stack?

Tags: c++, memory-management, callstack

If the alloca() function gets called multiple times in a particular function is it guaranteed that all the stack segments allocated by it form a contiguous part of stack memory altogether?

Comment: Note that `alloca()` is non-standard, and there's probably little reason to use it in C++.

Comment: Don't use `alloca()`, see http://c-faq.com/malloc/alloca.html

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Agreed.  The main reason to use `alloca` is to ensure that the memory is freed even if you return using `longjmp`.  And of course, you shouldn't ever use `longjmp` in C++, since it doesn't call destructors when unwinding the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it guaranteed that all the stack segments allocated by it form a contiguous part of stack memory altogether?

No. If it were guaranteed, you could read all about it in it's documentation. `alloca` is an *implementation defined* function (the only one who could tell you what guarantees you have on it is your compiler's implementer).

It is also non-standard, unsafe, and non-portable (basically worse than using `malloc` and `free` in C++).

Unless you want to know how legacy code (using it) behaves, the only think you get by using it, is lower code quality.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe.  There is no `alloca` in C, C++ or Posix.  It is
a frequent extension in Unix based systems, but each system
defines it like it wants.  (The documentation of the GNU version
suggests that they would be contiguous, but I see no actual
guarantee.)

Answer (score 1):

As said by others the short answer is 'no'.

However reading implementer docs or even reverse engineering could allow you to make such assumptions (or not).

I ran this example at [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) which says `void*` is size 8 and diff is (-32):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  void *var1 = alloca(sizeof var1);
  std::cout << "sizeof var1: " << sizeof var1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "var1 addr: " << var1 << std::endl;
  void *var2 = alloca(sizeof var2);
  std::cout << "var2 addr: " << var2 << std::endl;
  intptr_t diff = (intptr_t)var2 - (intptr_t)var1;  
  std::cout << "addr diff: " << diff << std::endl;
}
```

Huh. Not contiguous. Maybe there is some simple padding going on.

Making allocation of size 128 byte gives a diff of (-144):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int size = 128;
  void *var1 = alloca(size);
  std::cout << "var1 addr: " << var1 << std::endl;
  void *var2 = alloca(size);
  std::cout << "var2 addr: " << var2 << std::endl;
  intptr_t diff = (intptr_t)var2 - (intptr_t)var1;  
  std::cout << "addr diff: " << diff << std::endl;
}
```

Hm. Alignment is not restricted to 32-byte...

Further reverse engineering left as student excercise.

(From just two tests I have a pretty good guess of what is going on without any documentation. Making a few more should narrow it down quite a bit.)